# How to list all fields of a content type with views?

Tags: views

I would like to create a product comparison view. Each product has lots of features which all need to appear in the comparison view. Each feature is a separate field in the “product” content type.

Instead of *manually* adding all fields of the “product” content type to my view, I’d like to have *all fields added automatically* to the view – for example when adding a new field to the “product” content type. Is this possible?

Bonus question: can I add all fields to the view by default and later exclude only a few of them?

---

**Edit:** Further Notes

I’d like to create a comparison table where corresponding features appear in the same row with a single row/column label for the feature. Many features are optional, though. Therefore I need the feature fields of the “product” content type to be available as separate fields in the view – so that I can properly align them in the table.

Comment: Do you have Views UI module installed ? `;)`

Comment: @NikhilM Sure :-)  I’m just wondering whether I’m not seeing the wood for the trees …

Answer (score 1):

According to me the best way to configure a view is to use display modes ("Show: content" and select the display mode).
So that when I add a field to a content type I just have to configure the "Manage Display" sections (1 per view mode) of the content type.

Note that sometimes I need extra fields to render, to use as token for other settings (rewrite a field, header/footer text, more link,...) or to make grouping. To achieve this I switch the "Show" option to fields and add a "Content: Rendered Node" field (that comes with Entity API module). Then the "Show complete entity" display option of this field allows you to choose a display mode (Full content, teaser, list item or any other display mode) and render the nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer which describes a really interesting idea. Unfortunately for my particular use case this idea doesn’t help. I admit, though, that this couldn’t be inferred from my original question (which I will update accordingly in a minute).